# Denegar submit con AJAX, y subir imagen a base de datos

Tags: php, html, ajax

Estoy tratando de hacer un formulario de registro simple utilizando AJAX, necesito poder realizar este registro sin recargar la pagina.
Tengo dos problemas, no logro impedir la recarga de la web pese a poner un return false con JavaScript, y despues se me presenta otro problema que es subir una imagen mediante AJAX a la base de datos usando PHP.

```js
< script >
  function miFuncion() {
    var dni = document.getElementById('dni').value;
    var nombre = document.getElementById('nombre').value;
    var data = "dni=" + dni + "&nombre=" + nombre;

    var obj = new XMLHttpRequest();
    obj.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (obj.readyState == 4 && obj.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("msj").innerHTML = obj.responseText;
      }
    }

    obj.open("POST", "info.php", true);
    obj.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    obj.send(data);

    return false;
  }
  </script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>AJAX</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="inicio.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return miFuncion()">
    DNI <br><input type="text" id="dni" name="dni"> <br> NOMBRE <br><input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre"><br>
    <input type="file" name="imagen"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="enviar">
    <div id="msj"></div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

He revisado tu código y al parecer el problema de la recarga de pagina se puede deber a un error de sintaxis en tu editor. Ya que testee tu codigo en codepen y no recarga la pagina.

Por otro lado con respecto a la carga de imágenes con XMLHttpRequest. Te recomiendo que investigues un poco sobre el objeto formData.

Aquí te dejo uno ejemplo y unos enlaces que espero que te ayuden.

HTML:

```html
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" name="fileinfo" id="fileinfo">
  <label>Your email address:</label>
  <input type="email" autocomplete="on" autofocus name="userid" placeholder="email" required size="32" maxlength="64"><br />
  <label>Custom file ID:</label>
  <input type="text" name="fileid" size="12" maxlength="32"><br />
  <label>File to stash:</label>
  <input type="file" name="file" required>
</form>
<div id="output"></div>
<a href="javascript:sendForm()">Stash the file!</a>
```

JS:

```
function sendForm() {
  var output = document.getElementById("output");
  var data = new FormData(document.getElementById("fileinfo"));

  data.append("CustomField", "This is some extra data");

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", "stash.pl", false)
  xhr.send(data);
  if (xhr.status == 200) {
    output.innerHTML += "Uploaded!<br />";
  } else {
    output.innerHTML += "Error " + xhr.status + " occurred uploading your file.<br />";
  }
}
```

El ejemplo lo obtuve del siguiente enlace:
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Sending_files_using_a_FormData_object

Mas información:
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Guide/Usando_Objetos_FormData

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, es que estuve investigando el objeto formData y no consegui entender como usar el metodo append siendo el input de tipo file. "data.append("CustomField", "This is some extra data");", aqui es donde tengo la duda.

Comment: El metodo append solo agrega mas datos al objeto FormData. Adaptado al ejemplo a tu codigo deberias tener algo como esto por cada campo:     var nombre = document.getElementById('nombre').value; data.append("nombre", nombre);                                  Al final el objeto FormData tendria todos los datos de tu formulario incluyendo la imagen.

Comment: Vale gracias, lo que no sabia era capturar el archivo con javaScript, pero ya lo consegui, muchas gracias por tu ayuda.